# in F# on MAC OSX and Ubuntu I get an error running FSI in 4.0

Tags: macos, f#, ubuntu, f#-interactive

I need System.Numerics in F#

**EDIT** I think the question is can fsi run with the 4.0 runtime and if so how do I configure it

I run "mono /bin/Fsi" in the Fsharp 4.0 dir I get the following error in both OSX 10.6.4 and Ubuntu 10.1.

I am sure I am missing a path or something

Please note the paths are different on the MAC but I got the same error

error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'System.Numerics.dll' in any of
 /opt/mono-2.8/lib/mono/2.0
 /home/gary/Downloads/FSharp-2.0.0.0/v4.0/bin
 /home/gary/Downloads/FSharp-2.0.0.0/v4.0/bin/

On my MAcbook I copied the mono 4.0 bin dir to one of the above paths and Fsi loads but then it stops with this error.

Error FS0192: internal error: unreachable: GetGlobals

I have not tried this with the Ubuntu laptop

Any help would be appreciated.

G

Comment: You can specify the search path of ´fsi´ using the option ´I´ ("-I:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.8/lib/mono/4.0"). I still get the FS0192-error (on MacOSX) but at least don't have to copy anything to avoid the FS0078-error... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use cd /usr/lib/fsharp
then mono fsi.exe

your question brought me to search for fsi (before I could not find it)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `sudo install_mono.sh` from the F# directory? Also, I think you mean F# 2.0, right?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Mono is installed properly. I don't have my mac at work, so I use my Ubuntu desktop as example.

System.Numerics.dll belongs to Mono not F#. In my installation (Mono 2.8.1 and Ubuntu 10.10), that file is under the following directory

/usr/local/lib/mono/4.0/System.Numerics.dll