# Can fsi run with the 4.0 runtime on MAC OS and if so how do I configure it

Tags: macos, f#, f#-interactive

Kinda self explanatory...

I get a variety of errors when try to access 4.0 dlls in FSI. So rather than go through each one, I think the above question is the right one.

This is a repost more or less of my question here [in F# on MAC OSX and Ubuntu I get an error running FSI in 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156854/in-f-on-mac-osx-and-ubuntu-i-get-an-error-running-fsi-in-4-0)

Thanks

Gary

**Edit** I am trying to run the following in a demo on my MacBook with Mono 2.8 and fsharp. (The code was chosen by someone else)

```
open System.Numerics
open System

let maxIteration = 100

let modSquared (c : Complex) = c.Real * c.Real + c.Imaginary * c.Imaginary

type MandelbrotResult = 
    | DidNotEscape
    | Escaped of int

let mandelbrot c =
    let rec mandelbrotInner z iterations =
        if(modSquared z >= 4.0) 
            then Escaped iterations
        elif iterations = maxIteration
            then DidNotEscape
        else mandelbrotInner ((z * z) + c) (iterations + 1)
    mandelbrotInner c 0

for y in [-1.0..0.1..1.0] do
    for x in [-2.0..0.05..1.0] do
        match mandelbrot (Complex(x, y)) with
        | DidNotEscape -> Console.Write "#"
        | Escaped _ -> Console.Write " "
    Console.WriteLine ()
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "4.0 runtime"... the runtime is whatever version of Mono you are running; I believe the latest is 2.8. Similarly, the F# version is 2.0.0.0 (unless your using an older set on source files, but they'd be quite out-dated by now). Hate to be obvious, but are you sure the DLLs you are trying to access are supported by Mono?

Comment: Actually, after reading your other post, I think I can offer you this advice: on Windows, the only difference between the 2.0 and 4.0 builds of F# are the physical DLLs where certain types are defined, and (in a very small number of cases) the namespaces in which certain types are defined. As such, you man not actually NEED the 4.0 build of F#. For instance, in the 2.0 build of F# System.Numerics.BigInteger is defined in Fsharp.Core.dll. However, it was moved to its own assembly (System.Numerics.dll) in the 4.0 build.

Comment: Is this the F# CTP (binaries), or is this F# built-from-source?

Comment: Brian I believe it is the binaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the ZIP binaries and tried to run the 4.0 version on MacOS. Initially, I get the same error as you (could not locate `BigInteger`). This can be fixed by adding the `-I` command line argument, but then I got another error and I'm not yet sure what to do about this one:

```
fsmac:fsharp4 tomas$ mono Fsi.exe 
  -I:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.8/lib/mono/4.0/

Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> 
error FS0192: internal error: unreachable: GetGlobals
```

**EDIT** Here is another (unsuccessful) attempt. This looks like a Mono bug, because the `UnsafeLoadFrom` method doesn't seem to exist on Mono (runtime 4.0). At least, I cannot see it in the MonoDevelop IDE in C# projects (when I change runtime to 4.0)

```
fsmac:fsharp4 tomas$ mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 Fsi.exe --noframework 
  -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.8/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll 
  -r:FSharp.Core.dll 

Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> Missing method System.Reflection.Assembly::UnsafeLoadFrom(string) in 
assembly /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.8/lib/mono/4.0/
mscorlib.dll, referenced in assembly /Users/tomas/Programs/fsharp4/
FSharp.Compiler.dll
```

Comment: I have the same error. On the Mac I copied the dlls into the f# bin folder and on Ubuntu I used the -I switch Either way I get the same error

Comment: @Gee: Can you check my next attempt (I added it to the answer)?

Comment: ok, The complex numbers are working... (see above) now it fails on the part of the  code 

type MandelbrotResult = 
    | DidNotEscape
    | Escaped of int

with 
error FS0193: Operation is not supported.

Comment: @Gee: Do you have F# November CTP update (released about a week ago)? This error used to happen on earlier versions of F# on Mono 2.8. November CTP fixes this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=effc5bc4-c3df-4172-ad1c-bc62935861c5&displaylang=en

Comment: ok , I got the new CTP but then that created more errors and fsi would crash with mscorlib incompatibilities using the same mono fsi command line. I will keep working on it.

Comment: I uninstalled f# and the installed it into /lib in my home directory. This is where I store most TP code. I added the path to MONO_PATH. I ran install_mono.sh and it worked. I did create 2 aliases "fsi" for the OOB Fsi and fsi4 with the command line you provided. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing the F# assemblies in the GAC. To do this:

1. Open up a Terminal
2. Go to the directory you downloaded the F# distribution to and then cd to `bin/`
3. Install every DLL in the GAC using `gacutil`

`$ cd FSharp-2.0.0.0/bin/; for a in *.dll; do sudo gacutil -i $a; done`

You'll probably want to do the same the PowerPack.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks this may work but I got it working with the above sequence, see my comment to the previous answer.