# When compiling an F# project on macOS, how do I ensure the compiler can find the Mono assembly 'System.Numerics.dll'?

Tags: .net, macos, f#, msbuild, mono

I'm trying to build a .NET Framework 4.7.2, F#, class-library project¹ under Mono on macOS.

However, when I add a dependency² on an external project, I become unable to build; receiving an error like this ([full log](https://gist.github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/90c251b28a9736a653bf72a517e910da)):

```sh
$ msbuild FSharpMod.sln -restore -p:Configuration=Release
...
FSC : error FS0078: Unable to find the file 'System.Numerics.dll' in any of /Users/ec/.nuget/packages/krafs.rimworld.ref/1.3.3087/ref/net472 /Users/ec/Sync/Code/FSharpMod/Source/FSharpModLibrary /usr/local/Cellar/mono/6.12.0.122/lib/mono/fsharp/ [/Users/ec/Sync/Code/FSharpMod/Source/FSharpModLibrary/FSharpModLibrary.fsproj]
Done Building Project "/Users/ec/Sync/Code/FSharpMod/Source/FSharpModLibrary/FSharpModLibrary.fsproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "/Users/ec/Sync/Code/FSharpMod/FSharpMod.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

So, [supposedly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4626249/31897), `System.Numerics.dll` is a Mono-specific thing. Notably, if I:

- Build this simple test on Windows, i.e. not under Mono,
- remove any reference to an external dependency,
- or switch it over to C# instead of F#,

... then it compiles fine; I don't run into this problem. As far as we can tell, it's only *the specific combination* of macOS/Mono/external-dependency/F# that starts complaining about `System.Numerics.dll`.

My tentative understanding is that this is probably some sort of build-configuration failure on my part; but nobody I've talked to has been able to hunt down what's causing this. Hoping someone with a deeper knowledge of the Microsoft build-system, FSharp, or Mono, will be able to help!

---

> 1. Literally just [the four-line auto-generated starter F# project](https://github.com/ELLIOTTCABLE/Tutorial-FSharp-Mod/blob/a1d75f12/Source/FSharpModLibrary/Library1.fs) from Visual Studio on Windows; nothing substantial.
> 2. The dependency in this case is [`Krafs.Rimworld.Ref`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Krafs.Rimworld.Ref); but I don't think it matters — I dug through the decompiled ILSpy output with ripgrep, and can't find a single reference to `System.Numerics`. This

Comment: This might help: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Numerics/

Comment: The log indicates that you installed Mono via Homebrew, so that some references were resolved to `/usr/local/Cellar/mono/6.12.0.122/lib/mono/4.7.2-api/`. That might confuse F# compiler somehow, but you might discuss with F# guys on GitHub https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues . Did you try to use `dotnet build`?

Comment: You might want to tag this question "F#"  rather than "C#".

Answer (score 1):

This builds fine for me
[Full log](https://gist.github.com/KoenigLear/b69ca6e6fc469117e2b5dfa2becc1b8e).  I think is the location of mono as @Lex li pointed out.

Mono for me is at

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono
```

and the libraries are at:

```
 /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.12.0/lib/mono/4.7.2-api/System.Numerics.dll
```

I suggest you uninstall using brew and install it using the package from mono org: https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-mac